# debugging cherokee on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, cherokee

After installing cherokee on my arch linux instance,

```
pacman -S python2 cherokee rrdtool
```

I continued on to do some configuration via cherokee admin:-

```
cherokee-admin -xb
```

Hoping over to my browser, I attempted to access my cherokee admin via `its.ip.addr.ess:9090` and keyed in the corresponding admin and password.  It accepts the password but after attempting to load the cherokee admin web ui for a while, it failed and showed me a 503 error

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Since I specified `-x` in my cherokee-admin command above, I do see some tracebacks like this:-

```
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=1035 Port=4000
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=1041 Port=4000
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=1047 Port=4000
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=1054 Port=4000
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=1060 Port=4000
```

But that doesn't really help me in my debugging efforts.

Any idea how I can go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

The `-t` option is required to use a unix domain socket internally.

This is required if `ipv6` is enabled for your box. Which is the case for this specific box of mine.

Mystery solved.